# PowerShell Test-Connection -TimeToLive error?

Tags: powershell

I don't know what happened, but everytime I enter the following command:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName TARGET -TimeToLive 6
```

I got the following error:

```
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'TARGET' failed: Problem with some part of the filterspec or providerspecific buffer in general
At line:1 char:16
+ Test-Connection <<<<  -ComputerName TARGET -TimeToLive 6
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (TARGET:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Funnily enough, if I don't the `-TimeToLive` parameter, e.g.:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName TARGET
Test-Connection -ComputerName TARGET -Count 2
```

The commands work as expected! And doing `Get-Help Test-Connection` tantalizingly shows that `-TimeToLive` is *indeed* a valid parameter.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me with the -TimeToLive parameter. Can you check this on a different computer?

Comment: @ravikanth It sure does work on other computers. IIRC, it *used* to work correctly, but now it works no longer. What could possibly be the cause, I wonder...

Comment: Does the same error result when `localhost` is tested?

Comment: ... not sure, please see my self-answer.

Comment: As an aside: The error message you would see if an unsupported parameter _were_ the problem (it's not): `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '...'`; the error at hand is not a syntax error, but a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Every IP packet that gets sent out has a TTL field which is set to a relatively high number (in the case of ping in a LAN is 128). As the packet traverses the network, the TTL field gets decreased by one by each router it goes through; when the TTL drops to 0, the packet is discarded by the router. The IP spec says that the TTL should be set to 60 (though it's 255 for ping packets). The main purpose of this is so that a packet doesn't live forever on the network and will eventually die when it is deemed "lost."

It's possible that in you LAN a TTL of 6 isn't enougth to reach the destination.

In my environment only a TTL of 1 pinging on two hop subnet return your error, and is right, I have only one core router/switch for multiple vlans and a local router each  differnet subnet/domain.

Comment: The `-TimeToLive` parameter in PowerShell is **not** the IP packet's TTL field. It should properly be named as `-TimeOut`, but the name already stuck.

Comment: @pepoluan mmmhh... I think is the TTL field ( is the ping -i, nothin to do with the -w paramenter of ping.exe: Timeout in milliseconds to wait for each reply. )

Comment: Could you try if  `ping.exe -i 6 TARGET` gives same result?

Comment: I'm away from the computer right now (it's my workstation at the office), so I can't try ping-ing. However I am positively sure that `-TimeToLive` in this case means 'timeout' : `Get-Help Test-Connection`says so. Besides, the error message is *not* about being unable to reach the TARGET, but about some kind of syntax error.

Comment: Seeing your answer works test-connection too... Then was not a usefully test :)

Comment: From what I can tell: `ping -i 6` _is_ the equivalent of `Test-Connection -TimeToLive 6` (i.e., a max. _hop count_ rather than a _timeout in seconds_), and the PowerShell documentation is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This answer is based on my own experiments. Do let me know if I'm wrong.

This answer draws on [CB.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186363/45375).</sup>

**tl;dr**

- **`-TimeToLive`, despite what the [`Test-Connection` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Test-Connection?view=powershell-5.1) says (still as of PSv5.1 and [also in the source-code repository on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/blob/staging/reference/6/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Test-Connection.md)<sup>[1]</sup>
  ), is NOT a *timeout* in *seconds*, but the *maximum count of hops*** a packet can make before it is considered expired.

  - As such, it is analogous to `ping.exe`'s `-i <TTL>` parameter.
  - `Test-Connection`'s default value for `-TimeToLive` - `80` - provides a clue that it is *not* a timeout in *seconds*, as that would be excessively high.
  - `Test-Connection` has NO equivalent to `ping.exe`'s truly time-based `-w <ms>` timeout parameter.
- The **obscure error message** in this case (`problem with some part of the filterspec or providerspecific buffer in general`) **most likely stems from a packet having expired in transit, due to the low TTL** (hop-count limit) value.

  - `ping.exe` would report the much more helpful `TTL expired in transit` in that event.

---

**TTL (*Time*-to-Live) is a *misnomer*** in practice, which is a problem that has been corrected in IPv6, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#IP_packets) tells us (emphasis mine):

> ***In theory*, under IPv4, time to live is measured in *seconds***, although every host that passes the datagram must reduce the TTL by at least one unit. ***In practice*, the TTL field is *reduced by one on every hop*.** To reflect this practice, the **field is renamed *hop limit* in IPv6**.

While it is therefore understandable that confusion arises around what TTL truly represents, it is unfortunate, that the misinformation in the `Test-Connection` documentation hasn't been corrected in many years.

---

<sup>[1] I've opened [an issue there](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1504) to keep track of the problem.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Okay, after several weeks of non-stop work, I restarted my Laptop last night just before I went home.

This morning, amazingly `-TimeToLive` works again!!

So, my *main* problem of "not being able to use `-TimeToLive`" has been solved...

... but I'm still wondering, what had happened previously that `-TimeToLive` caused errors ...

Comment: The fact that you observed this on a _laptop_ is a further clue that `-TimeToLive` is not a _timeout in seconds_, but a _max. hop count_: perhaps at the time you rebooted you happened to be connected to a _different_ network, where the target host now happened to be reachable with _6 or fewer hops_.

Comment: Okay this had been quite a long time ago, but I remember that at the moment I was connected to my company's network using cables. Even though I am given the privilege to connect to the WiFi (used by upper management), I _always_ use cable (Gigabit Ethernet FTW). I think it was a simple situation of Windows being Windows.

Comment: No need to rely on memory from long ago: Find a server where `ping -i 1 -n 1` returns "TTL expired in transit" (virtually instantly, not after 1 _second_), and parallel that with `Test-Connection -TimeToLive 1 -Count 1` - you'll see that `ping` and `Test-Connection` fail in parallel. Keep incrementing the TTL value to see that both commands eventually start working with the same value; `ping -i ` expresses TTL as _hops_, and so does `Test-Connection -TimeToLive`, despite what the documentation claims. It shouldn't be too hard to verify this at a packet level.