# How to get the full help in show window in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How to get the full help in showwindow?
for eg: get-help get-service -full -showwindow.
-showwindow is only showing basic help, can i see the full help in showwindow?

Comment: click on the settings button in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`-ShowWindow`, by (arguably questionable) design, cannot be combined with `-Full`,

`-Detailed`, or `-Examples`.**

Instead, the *intent* is to **use`-ShowWindow` *by itself***, and then **use the `Settings` button in the top-right corner** of the window that pops up to select the sections that should be displayed - the **default behavior is to show *all* sections**.
A custom **section selection is *remembered*** between invocations.

Regrettably, **an apparent bug in PSv5 prevents display of the `DESCRIPTION` and `PARAMETERS` sections** (PSv3 and PSv4 are *not* affected; PSv3 is the earliest version to support `-ShowWindow`).

Even more regrettably, this bug is not an isolated incident: PowerShell, despite the innate power and flexibility of its help system, has a history of shoddy documentation, involving both regression bugs (such as this one) and [documentation errors that don't get corrected for years on end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408067/45375).

Comment: Thanks for the info.